# SVG Animation of Solid Lines

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to animate this bamboo like it's being drawn on the screen:

[image]

In my illustrator file, the drawing is all one solid line, but when animated, it becomes two thin lines with a transparent fill.  Is this something I need to fix in my code, or in my illustrator file?  Here's my code for the doodle:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 1900 1100" class="svg-content" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path class="path"   fill-opacity="0" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" 
    d="M216.5,430c13.5-11.8,24.6-24.8,31.3-41.5c3.7-9.2,6.6-18.7,9.3-28.3c2.8-9.8,5.9-19.6,8-29.6
c0.3-1.2-1.5-0.6-1.9-0.3c-9.5,7.5-16.8,18.8-23.7,28.7c-1.5,2.2,1.1,2.3,2.2,0.7c6.4-9.2,13.2-20.2,22.2-27.2
c-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.2-1.9-0.3c-2,9.7-5.1,19.3-7.8,28.8c-2.4,8.5-5.1,16.9-8.1,25.1c-3,8.1-6.8,16.1-12.1,23
c-5.2,7-12.3,13.5-18.8,19.2C213.2,430.1,214.7,431.6,216.5,430L216.5,430z M211.4,428c10.1-14,21.5-28.2,26.6-45
c3.7-12.3,3.9-25.1,3.6-37.8c-0.3-13.9-0.7-28.4-2.8-42.1c-0.2-1.5-2.7,0.4-3,0.9c-6.7,9-10.6,20.6-14.4,31
c-4.6,12.6-7.9,25.9-9.7,39.2c-0.9,6.5-1,13.2-1.1,19.7c-0.1,4.6,0.4,9.3-0.1,13.9c-0.7,6.7-2.7,13.7-2.6,20.4
c0,2.1,3.6-0.3,3.6-1.8c-0.1-6.3,1.7-12.9,2.5-19.1c1.2-9.8,0.2-19.9,0.8-29.8c0.9-12.8,4-25.9,8.1-38.1
c3.9-11.5,7.9-24.8,15.3-34.7c-1,0.3-2,0.6-3,0.9c2.1,13.5,2.4,27.8,2.7,41.4c0.3,12.4,0.2,25-3.4,36.9
c-4.8,16.1-15.9,29.7-25.6,43.2C207.3,429.6,210.2,429.8,211.4,428L211.4,428z M87.2,151.5c-0.2,16.7,0.3,33.3-0.4,50
c-0.6,15.8-0.4,31.7-1.3,47.5c-0.9,15.7-1.7,31.6-2.3,47.4c-0.7,16.5-1.4,32.9-1.4,49.4c-0.1,35.7-0.4,71.5-0.2,107.2
c0.1,13.2,0.2,26.4,0.2,39.6c0,2.8,4.8-0.4,4.8-2.4c-0.1-28.8-0.3-57.6-0.5-86.5c-0.3-48.9,0.7-97.9,3.6-146.7
c1-17.4,1.3-34.9,1.7-52.3c0.2-8.6,0.6-17.2,0.9-25.8c0.3-9.9-0.5-19.9-0.3-29.8C92.1,146.2,87.2,149.4,87.2,151.5L87.2,151.5z
 M88.4,149.8c0.7-1,0.3-0.9-1.2,0.4c-1.1,0.6-2.3,1-3.5,1.4c-2,0.6-4.1,1-6.2,1.3c-3.9,0.5-7.8,0.2-11.7,0.1
c-3.6-0.1-22.9,0.8-19.8-7.1c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.5-1.8,2.3c1.3-0.8,4.9,0,6.4,0c1.8-0.1,3.6-0.5,5.4-0.6c3.4-0.2,6.8-0.1,10.2-0.2
c7-0.3,14-0.8,20.8,1c2,0.5,5.8-4,3.6-4.6c-9.5-2.5-19.1-0.8-28.8-0.9c-2.9,0-5.7,0.5-8.5,0.6c-2.2,0.1-4.4-0.3-6.5,0.1
c-3.3,0.5-5.8,2.8-5.7,6.3c0.1,4.2,3.7,6.3,7.4,6.9c6.5,1.1,13.1,0.9,19.6,1.1c7.8,0.3,21.5-0.8,25-9.3
C94.3,145.4,89.2,147.9,88.4,149.8L88.4,149.8z M90.1,224.4c-6,0.5-11.6,2.9-17.5,3.6c-7.3,0.8-15.3,0.5-22.5-0.6
c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c7,1.1,15,1.7,22,0.9c6.4-0.7,12.6-3.2,19-3.8C89.4,229,92.8,224.2,90.1,224.4L90.1,224.4z M82.6,344.2
c-2.1,2.2-3.5,2.8-6.7,3.4c-3.3,0.6-6.6,0.5-9.9,0.5c-7.3-0.1-14.3-1.2-21.5-2.5c-2.1-0.4-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c9,1.6,17.6,2.8,26.9,2.6
c6.7-0.2,12.4-1.4,16.9-6.3C87.3,343.9,85.1,341.5,82.6,344.2L82.6,344.2z M42,149.7c0.3,44.3,2.2,88.6,1.4,132.9
c-0.4,22.2-1.8,44.4-2.5,66.6c-0.7,22.6-1.4,45.2-2.1,67.8c-0.4,12.4-0.8,24.8-1.3,37.3c-0.2,6.2-0.5,12.4-0.8,18.6
c-0.1,3.2-0.5,6.5-0.4,9.8c0.1,2.4,0.8,4.6,0.6,7c-0.2,2.7,4.7-0.4,4.8-2.4c0.1-1.6-0.1-3.1-0.3-4.7c-0.4-3-0.1-6,0-9.1
c0.2-5.5,0.5-11.1,0.7-16.6c0.4-11.1,0.8-22.2,1.2-33.3c0.7-22.3,1.4-44.5,2.1-66.8c1.4-44.8,3.4-89.3,2.7-134.1
c-0.4-25.3-1.1-50.4-1.3-75.4C46.8,144.4,42,147.7,42,149.7L42,149.7z M7.5,37c0.4,59.5,3,119,1.8,178.5C8.7,244.9,7,274.4,6,303.8
c-1,30.2-1.8,60.4-2.8,90.6c-0.5,16.4-1.1,32.8-1.7,49.1c-0.3,8.5-0.7,17-1,25.5c-0.2,3.9-0.6,7.9-0.5,11.7c0.1,3.2,1.1,6.2,0.7,9.4
c-0.4,3.6,6.1-0.6,6.5-3.3c0.3-2.6-0.3-4.9-0.6-7.5c-0.3-3.2,0-6.5,0.2-9.7c0.3-7.8,0.7-15.7,1-23.5C8.4,431,8.9,416,9.4,400.9
c1-29.5,1.8-59.1,2.8-88.6c0.9-29.5,1.9-58.9,3.2-88.3c1.3-30.1,0.8-60.2,0.3-90.3c-0.6-33.3-1.4-66.6-1.7-99.9
C13.9,30,7.5,34.3,7.5,37L7.5,37z M57.1,36.5c-0.2,17.7,0.2,35.4-0.5,53.2c-0.6,16.8-1.6,33.8-1.5,50.5c0,2.8,4.9-0.4,4.8-2.4
c-0.1-16.8,0.9-33.8,1.5-50.5c0.7-17.8,0.3-35.4,0.5-53.2C62,31.2,57.1,34.4,57.1,36.5L57.1,36.5z M58.3,34.8c0.7-1,0.3-0.9-1.2,0.4
c-1.1,0.6-2.3,1-3.5,1.4c-2,0.6-4.1,1-6.2,1.3c-3.9,0.5-7.8,0.2-11.7,0.1c-3.6-0.1-22.9,0.8-19.8-7.1c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.5-1.8,2.3
c1.3-0.8,4.9,0,6.4,0c1.8-0.1,3.6-0.5,5.4-0.6c3.4-0.2,6.8-0.1,10.2-0.2c7-0.3,14-0.8,20.8,1c2,0.5,5.8-4,3.6-4.6
C51,26.3,41.4,28,31.7,27.9c-2.9,0-5.7,0.5-8.5,0.6c-2.2,0.1-4.4-0.3-6.5,0.1c-3.3,0.5-5.8,2.8-5.7,6.3c0.1,4.2,3.7,6.3,7.4,6.9
c6.5,1.1,13.1,0.9,19.6,1.1c7.8,0.3,21.5-0.8,25-9.3C64.2,30.4,59.1,32.9,58.3,34.8L58.3,34.8z M60,109.4c-6,0.5-11.6,2.9-17.5,3.6
c-7.3,0.8-15.3,0.5-22.5-0.6c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c7,1.1,15,1.7,22,0.9c6.4-0.7,12.6-3.2,19-3.8C59.3,114,62.7,109.2,60,109.4
L60,109.4z M44.6,370.7c-11.2,2.7-22,3.6-33.6,1.7c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c6,1,13.3,1.8,19.3,1.3c5.7-0.5,10.8-1.7,16.3-3.1
C45.1,374.8,47.9,369.9,44.6,370.7L44.6,370.7z M46.1,232.6c-10.7,1.4-21.1-0.2-31.6-2c-2.1-0.4-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6
c10.8,1.9,21.6,3.6,32.6,2.2C45.5,237.1,48.8,232.3,46.1,232.6L46.1,232.6z M91.1,182c-0.1-4.9,2.5-10.2,4.3-14.7
c1.9-4.6,3.8-9.2,5.7-13.9c4-10.2,9.7-18.8,16.2-27.7c6-8.1,11.3-16.8,17.8-24.6c3.6-4.3,7.6-8.1,11.9-11.6c3.7-3,7.7-7.5,11.8-9.8
c-0.7,0-1.3,0-2,0c1.9,2.3,0.9,7.7,0.9,10.5c0,3.9-0.1,7.9-0.4,11.8c-0.6,7.8-2.2,15.5-4,23.1c-3.5,14.8-8.8,29.4-15.3,43.2
c-6.2,13.1-13.9,26.9-23.3,37.9c-4.7,5.5-10.2,10.2-15.6,15.1c-2.5,2.3-4.8,4.7-7,7.3c-1.6,1.8-3.3,3-4,5.3c-1,3.3,4,0.6,4.6-1.3
c0.3-1,4.7-5.3,6-6.6c2.7-2.7,5.7-5.2,8.5-7.8c5.4-5,10.5-10.3,14.9-16.2c8.8-12.1,16.5-25.7,22.4-39.4
c6.3-14.6,11.5-29.7,14.8-45.3c1.6-7.4,2.7-14.7,3-22.3c0.2-4.2,0.2-8.5,0.2-12.7c0-2.4,0.2-4.8-1.5-6.7c-0.5-0.6-1.5-0.2-2,0
c-4.3,2.4-7.9,6.4-11.7,9.4c-4.3,3.5-8.4,7-12.2,11c-8,8.6-14.2,19-21.1,28.4c-6.5,8.8-12.5,17.5-16.6,27.7
c-2.2,5.4-4.4,10.8-6.6,16.2c-2,4.9-4.7,10.5-4.6,15.9C86.3,187.2,91.1,184,91.1,182L91.1,182z M95.8,160.7c0.4-3.8,3.3-8,4.9-11.5
c1.2-2.5,2.3-5.1,3.5-7.6c2.7-6.2,5.1-12.4,6.5-19c2.8-13.3,4.6-27,6.1-40.5c1.6-14,2.6-28.1,2.7-42.2c0-6.9-0.1-13.7-0.5-20.6
c-0.3-6.1,0.7-12.6-0.3-18.6c-0.2-1.4-2.3-0.3-2.9,0c-3.9,2.5-5.8,7.4-8,11.3c-3,5.5-5.9,11-8.3,16.7c-5.3,12.3-9.9,25-14.1,37.7
c-4.1,12.5-8.5,25.4-10.7,38.4c-2.2,13.4-3.4,27-3.9,40.6c-0.1,2.8,4.8-0.4,4.8-2.4c0.4-12,1.6-24,3.2-36
c1.7-12.4,5.7-24.5,9.5-36.5c3.5-11.2,7.5-22.2,11.7-33.1c2.3-5.9,4.7-11.9,7.6-17.6c1.2-2.4,2.5-4.8,3.8-7.2c1.3-2.3,3-7.3,5.3-8.7
c-1,0-1.9,0-2.9,0c0.6,3.5,0,6.9,0,10.4c0,3.3,0.2,6.7,0.4,10c0.3,6.9,0.4,13.8,0.3,20.7c-0.2,13.8-1.3,27.5-2.9,41.2
c-1.6,13.6-3.2,27.6-6.4,41c-1.7,7-4.8,13.6-7.8,20.2c-2.3,4.9-5.9,10.1-6.5,15.6C90.6,165.9,95.6,162.7,95.8,160.7L95.8,160.7z
 M117.6,488.6c3.5-24,0.7-48.3,1.1-72.5c0-1.8-2.1-1.1-2.9-0.4c-1.5,1.1-4.5,5.2-1.4,6.5c3.6,1.5,4.7-4.5,4.3-6.5s-3.6,0.6-4,1.2
c-7.9,10-13.4,21.5-17.9,33.4c-2.4,6.3-4.6,12.6-7,18.9c-1.1,2.9-2.2,5.7-3.4,8.6c-1.5,3.6-1.9,7.5-3.3,11.1
c-1.2,3.1,3.9,0.5,4.6-1.3c1.2-3.1,1.5-6.4,2.6-9.6c1.1-2.9,2.3-5.7,3.4-8.6c2.2-5.8,4.2-11.6,6.4-17.3c4.5-12.1,9.7-23.9,17.8-34.1
c-1.3,0.4-2.7,0.8-4,1.2c0.1,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.2,1.4c1-1,2-2,3.1-2.9c1.5-0.2,1.3,0.3-0.4,1.5c-1-0.1-1.9-0.3-2.9-0.4
c-0.5,24.2,2.3,48.4-1.1,72.5C112.4,493.7,117.3,490.6,117.6,488.6L117.6,488.6z M162.8,233.2c0.1,11-0.7,22-0.1,33
c0.6,11.5,0.7,23.1,0.9,34.6c0.2,10.3,0.5,20.8,1.1,31.1c0.6,10.7,0.4,21.5,1.2,32.2c0.2,2.9,5-0.4,4.8-2.4
c-0.8-10.3-0.9-20.7-1.1-31c-0.2-10.7-1-21.5-1.1-32.2c-0.2-11.3-0.4-22.6-0.9-33.8c-0.5-11.3,0.2-22.5,0-33.8
C167.6,227.9,162.8,231.2,162.8,233.2L162.8,233.2z M162,232.9c2.3,3.9,8.1,5.1,12.2,5.8c5.7,1,11.5,0.6,17.3,0.4
c7.1-0.3,19.3,0.2,21.4-8.9c0.7-3.1-0.3-4.7-3.4-5.1c-4.5-0.6-9.6-0.6-14.2-0.6c-9.6,0.1-19-1.6-28.4,0.9c-1.9,0.5-4.8,5.4-1.5,4.6
c12.1-3.2,25.4,0,37.8-0.2c2,0,8.6,1,3.1,3.5c-1.4,0.6-4,0.5-5.5,0.6c-4.2,0.4-8.3,0.4-12.5,0.5c-6.2,0.2-18.3,0.6-22-5.8
C165.3,227.1,160.8,230.9,162,232.9L162,232.9z M164.8,309.5c6.3,0.5,12.3,3,18.6,3.7c6.8,0.8,14.5,0.2,21.2-0.8
c1.9-0.3,5.2-5.2,2.6-4.8c-7,1.1-14.8,1.5-21.9,0.8c-6.1-0.7-11.8-3.1-17.9-3.6C165.4,304.6,161.9,309.3,164.8,309.5L164.8,309.5z
 M177.9,430.3c11,1.5,21.7-0.2,32.6-2.1c2-0.3,4.9-5.2,1.5-4.6c-10.1,1.7-20.2,3.4-30.5,2C179.4,425.4,175.8,430.1,177.9,430.3
L177.9,430.3z M207.2,231.5c0.9,34.6-2.5,69.1-1.7,103.6s3.4,68.9,4,103.4c0.1,9.2,0.3,18.4-0.3,27.5c-0.3,4.6-1.2,9.1-1.2,13.7
c0,4.1,0.7,8.1,1.3,12.1c0.3,2.1,5.1-1.3,4.7-3.4c-0.6-4-1.3-7.9-1.2-12c0.1-4,0.9-8,1.1-11.9c0.6-8.3,0.5-16.6,0.4-24.9
c-0.3-16.7-1-33.4-1.6-50c-1.4-34.2-3-68.2-1.7-102.4c0.7-19.4,1.5-38.8,1-58.2C212,226.2,207.1,229.5,207.2,231.5L207.2,231.5z
 M133.3,368.5c0,41,0.1,82,2.8,122.9c0.2,2.9,5-0.4,4.8-2.4c-2.8-40.9-2.8-81.9-2.8-122.9C138.1,363.3,133.3,366.5,133.3,368.5
L133.3,368.5z M132.4,368.3c2.3,3.9,8.1,5.1,12.2,5.8c5.7,1,11.5,0.6,17.3,0.4c7.1-0.3,19.3,0.2,21.4-8.9c0.7-3.1-0.3-4.7-3.4-5.1
c-4.5-0.6-9.6-0.6-14.2-0.6c-9.6,0.1-19-1.6-28.4,0.9c-1.9,0.5-4.8,5.4-1.5,4.6c12.1-3.2,25.4,0,37.8-0.2c2,0,8.6,1,3.1,3.5
c-1.4,0.6-4,0.5-5.5,0.6c-4.2,0.4-8.3,0.4-12.5,0.5c-6.2,0.2-18.3,0.6-22-5.8C135.8,362.4,131.3,366.3,132.4,368.3L132.4,368.3z
 M135.2,444.8c6.3,0.5,12.3,3,18.6,3.7c6.8,0.8,14.5,0.2,21.2-0.8c1.9-0.3,5.2-5.2,2.6-4.8c-7,1.1-14.8,1.5-21.9,0.8
c-6.1-0.7-11.8-3.1-17.9-3.6C135.9,439.9,132.4,444.6,135.2,444.8L135.2,444.8z M177.7,366.8c-0.4,41.9-2.3,83.7-1.3,125.6
c0.1,2.8,4.9-0.4,4.8-2.4c-1-41.9,0.9-83.7,1.3-125.6C182.5,361.6,177.7,364.8,177.7,366.8L177.7,366.8z"/>
</svg>
```

With the following animation:

```
.path {
stroke-dasharray: 1000;
stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
animation: dash 2.5s linear normal forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
@keyframes dash {
from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}
to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Add, please, the patch code, without it no one can help you

Comment: @Alexandr_T - thank you, I've added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a line drawing animation, you need to know exactly its length.

```
<script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#path');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Path length - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

The length of the path turned out to be `7937px`

For the animation of the line we will use the patch attribute `stroke-dashoffset`

If you decrease the value of the attribute from the maximum value of `7937px` to zero, the line will be drawn from zero to the final length.

### CSS solution

```css
.path {
    fill:none;
    stroke:#51712D;
 stroke-width="3" 
    stroke-dashoffset:7937;
    stroke-dasharray:7937;
    animation: Final_stroke 48s ease forwards;
        } 

    @keyframes Final_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 7937;
    }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 1900 1100" class="svg-content" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path class="path"    
    d="M216.5,430c13.5-11.8,24.6-24.8,31.3-41.5c3.7-9.2,6.6-18.7,9.3-28.3c2.8-9.8,5.9-19.6,8-29.6
c0.3-1.2-1.5-0.6-1.9-0.3c-9.5,7.5-16.8,18.8-23.7,28.7c-1.5,2.2,1.1,2.3,2.2,0.7c6.4-9.2,13.2-20.2,22.2-27.2
c-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.2-1.9-0.3c-2,9.7-5.1,19.3-7.8,28.8c-2.4,8.5-5.1,16.9-8.1,25.1c-3,8.1-6.8,16.1-12.1,23
c-5.2,7-12.3,13.5-18.8,19.2C213.2,430.1,214.7,431.6,216.5,430L216.5,430z M211.4,428c10.1-14,21.5-28.2,26.6-45
c3.7-12.3,3.9-25.1,3.6-37.8c-0.3-13.9-0.7-28.4-2.8-42.1c-0.2-1.5-2.7,0.4-3,0.9c-6.7,9-10.6,20.6-14.4,31
c-4.6,12.6-7.9,25.9-9.7,39.2c-0.9,6.5-1,13.2-1.1,19.7c-0.1,4.6,0.4,9.3-0.1,13.9c-0.7,6.7-2.7,13.7-2.6,20.4
c0,2.1,3.6-0.3,3.6-1.8c-0.1-6.3,1.7-12.9,2.5-19.1c1.2-9.8,0.2-19.9,0.8-29.8c0.9-12.8,4-25.9,8.1-38.1
c3.9-11.5,7.9-24.8,15.3-34.7c-1,0.3-2,0.6-3,0.9c2.1,13.5,2.4,27.8,2.7,41.4c0.3,12.4,0.2,25-3.4,36.9
c-4.8,16.1-15.9,29.7-25.6,43.2C207.3,429.6,210.2,429.8,211.4,428L211.4,428z M87.2,151.5c-0.2,16.7,0.3,33.3-0.4,50
c-0.6,15.8-0.4,31.7-1.3,47.5c-0.9,15.7-1.7,31.6-2.3,47.4c-0.7,16.5-1.4,32.9-1.4,49.4c-0.1,35.7-0.4,71.5-0.2,107.2
c0.1,13.2,0.2,26.4,0.2,39.6c0,2.8,4.8-0.4,4.8-2.4c-0.1-28.8-0.3-57.6-0.5-86.5c-0.3-48.9,0.7-97.9,3.6-146.7
c1-17.4,1.3-34.9,1.7-52.3c0.2-8.6,0.6-17.2,0.9-25.8c0.3-9.9-0.5-19.9-0.3-29.8C92.1,146.2,87.2,149.4,87.2,151.5L87.2,151.5z
 M88.4,149.8c0.7-1,0.3-0.9-1.2,0.4c-1.1,0.6-2.3,1-3.5,1.4c-2,0.6-4.1,1-6.2,1.3c-3.9,0.5-7.8,0.2-11.7,0.1
c-3.6-0.1-22.9,0.8-19.8-7.1c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.5-1.8,2.3c1.3-0.8,4.9,0,6.4,0c1.8-0.1,3.6-0.5,5.4-0.6c3.4-0.2,6.8-0.1,10.2-0.2
c7-0.3,14-0.8,20.8,1c2,0.5,5.8-4,3.6-4.6c-9.5-2.5-19.1-0.8-28.8-0.9c-2.9,0-5.7,0.5-8.5,0.6c-2.2,0.1-4.4-0.3-6.5,0.1
c-3.3,0.5-5.8,2.8-5.7,6.3c0.1,4.2,3.7,6.3,7.4,6.9c6.5,1.1,13.1,0.9,19.6,1.1c7.8,0.3,21.5-0.8,25-9.3
C94.3,145.4,89.2,147.9,88.4,149.8L88.4,149.8z M90.1,224.4c-6,0.5-11.6,2.9-17.5,3.6c-7.3,0.8-15.3,0.5-22.5-0.6
c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c7,1.1,15,1.7,22,0.9c6.4-0.7,12.6-3.2,19-3.8C89.4,229,92.8,224.2,90.1,224.4L90.1,224.4z M82.6,344.2
c-2.1,2.2-3.5,2.8-6.7,3.4c-3.3,0.6-6.6,0.5-9.9,0.5c-7.3-0.1-14.3-1.2-21.5-2.5c-2.1-0.4-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c9,1.6,17.6,2.8,26.9,2.6
c6.7-0.2,12.4-1.4,16.9-6.3C87.3,343.9,85.1,341.5,82.6,344.2L82.6,344.2z M42,149.7c0.3,44.3,2.2,88.6,1.4,132.9
c-0.4,22.2-1.8,44.4-2.5,66.6c-0.7,22.6-1.4,45.2-2.1,67.8c-0.4,12.4-0.8,24.8-1.3,37.3c-0.2,6.2-0.5,12.4-0.8,18.6
c-0.1,3.2-0.5,6.5-0.4,9.8c0.1,2.4,0.8,4.6,0.6,7c-0.2,2.7,4.7-0.4,4.8-2.4c0.1-1.6-0.1-3.1-0.3-4.7c-0.4-3-0.1-6,0-9.1
c0.2-5.5,0.5-11.1,0.7-16.6c0.4-11.1,0.8-22.2,1.2-33.3c0.7-22.3,1.4-44.5,2.1-66.8c1.4-44.8,3.4-89.3,2.7-134.1
c-0.4-25.3-1.1-50.4-1.3-75.4C46.8,144.4,42,147.7,42,149.7L42,149.7z M7.5,37c0.4,59.5,3,119,1.8,178.5C8.7,244.9,7,274.4,6,303.8
c-1,30.2-1.8,60.4-2.8,90.6c-0.5,16.4-1.1,32.8-1.7,49.1c-0.3,8.5-0.7,17-1,25.5c-0.2,3.9-0.6,7.9-0.5,11.7c0.1,3.2,1.1,6.2,0.7,9.4
c-0.4,3.6,6.1-0.6,6.5-3.3c0.3-2.6-0.3-4.9-0.6-7.5c-0.3-3.2,0-6.5,0.2-9.7c0.3-7.8,0.7-15.7,1-23.5C8.4,431,8.9,416,9.4,400.9
c1-29.5,1.8-59.1,2.8-88.6c0.9-29.5,1.9-58.9,3.2-88.3c1.3-30.1,0.8-60.2,0.3-90.3c-0.6-33.3-1.4-66.6-1.7-99.9
C13.9,30,7.5,34.3,7.5,37L7.5,37z M57.1,36.5c-0.2,17.7,0.2,35.4-0.5,53.2c-0.6,16.8-1.6,33.8-1.5,50.5c0,2.8,4.9-0.4,4.8-2.4
c-0.1-16.8,0.9-33.8,1.5-50.5c0.7-17.8,0.3-35.4,0.5-53.2C62,31.2,57.1,34.4,57.1,36.5L57.1,36.5z M58.3,34.8c0.7-1,0.3-0.9-1.2,0.4
c-1.1,0.6-2.3,1-3.5,1.4c-2,0.6-4.1,1-6.2,1.3c-3.9,0.5-7.8,0.2-11.7,0.1c-3.6-0.1-22.9,0.8-19.8-7.1c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.5-1.8,2.3
c1.3-0.8,4.9,0,6.4,0c1.8-0.1,3.6-0.5,5.4-0.6c3.4-0.2,6.8-0.1,10.2-0.2c7-0.3,14-0.8,20.8,1c2,0.5,5.8-4,3.6-4.6
C51,26.3,41.4,28,31.7,27.9c-2.9,0-5.7,0.5-8.5,0.6c-2.2,0.1-4.4-0.3-6.5,0.1c-3.3,0.5-5.8,2.8-5.7,6.3c0.1,4.2,3.7,6.3,7.4,6.9
c6.5,1.1,13.1,0.9,19.6,1.1c7.8,0.3,21.5-0.8,25-9.3C64.2,30.4,59.1,32.9,58.3,34.8L58.3,34.8z M60,109.4c-6,0.5-11.6,2.9-17.5,3.6
c-7.3,0.8-15.3,0.5-22.5-0.6c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c7,1.1,15,1.7,22,0.9c6.4-0.7,12.6-3.2,19-3.8C59.3,114,62.7,109.2,60,109.4
L60,109.4z M44.6,370.7c-11.2,2.7-22,3.6-33.6,1.7c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c6,1,13.3,1.8,19.3,1.3c5.7-0.5,10.8-1.7,16.3-3.1
C45.1,374.8,47.9,369.9,44.6,370.7L44.6,370.7z M46.1,232.6c-10.7,1.4-21.1-0.2-31.6-2c-2.1-0.4-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6
c10.8,1.9,21.6,3.6,32.6,2.2C45.5,237.1,48.8,232.3,46.1,232.6L46.1,232.6z M91.1,182c-0.1-4.9,2.5-10.2,4.3-14.7
c1.9-4.6,3.8-9.2,5.7-13.9c4-10.2,9.7-18.8,16.2-27.7c6-8.1,11.3-16.8,17.8-24.6c3.6-4.3,7.6-8.1,11.9-11.6c3.7-3,7.7-7.5,11.8-9.8
c-0.7,0-1.3,0-2,0c1.9,2.3,0.9,7.7,0.9,10.5c0,3.9-0.1,7.9-0.4,11.8c-0.6,7.8-2.2,15.5-4,23.1c-3.5,14.8-8.8,29.4-15.3,43.2
c-6.2,13.1-13.9,26.9-23.3,37.9c-4.7,5.5-10.2,10.2-15.6,15.1c-2.5,2.3-4.8,4.7-7,7.3c-1.6,1.8-3.3,3-4,5.3c-1,3.3,4,0.6,4.6-1.3
c0.3-1,4.7-5.3,6-6.6c2.7-2.7,5.7-5.2,8.5-7.8c5.4-5,10.5-10.3,14.9-16.2c8.8-12.1,16.5-25.7,22.4-39.4
c6.3-14.6,11.5-29.7,14.8-45.3c1.6-7.4,2.7-14.7,3-22.3c0.2-4.2,0.2-8.5,0.2-12.7c0-2.4,0.2-4.8-1.5-6.7c-0.5-0.6-1.5-0.2-2,0
c-4.3,2.4-7.9,6.4-11.7,9.4c-4.3,3.5-8.4,7-12.2,11c-8,8.6-14.2,19-21.1,28.4c-6.5,8.8-12.5,17.5-16.6,27.7
c-2.2,5.4-4.4,10.8-6.6,16.2c-2,4.9-4.7,10.5-4.6,15.9C86.3,187.2,91.1,184,91.1,182L91.1,182z M95.8,160.7c0.4-3.8,3.3-8,4.9-11.5
c1.2-2.5,2.3-5.1,3.5-7.6c2.7-6.2,5.1-12.4,6.5-19c2.8-13.3,4.6-27,6.1-40.5c1.6-14,2.6-28.1,2.7-42.2c0-6.9-0.1-13.7-0.5-20.6
c-0.3-6.1,0.7-12.6-0.3-18.6c-0.2-1.4-2.3-0.3-2.9,0c-3.9,2.5-5.8,7.4-8,11.3c-3,5.5-5.9,11-8.3,16.7c-5.3,12.3-9.9,25-14.1,37.7
c-4.1,12.5-8.5,25.4-10.7,38.4c-2.2,13.4-3.4,27-3.9,40.6c-0.1,2.8,4.8-0.4,4.8-2.4c0.4-12,1.6-24,3.2-36
c1.7-12.4,5.7-24.5,9.5-36.5c3.5-11.2,7.5-22.2,11.7-33.1c2.3-5.9,4.7-11.9,7.6-17.6c1.2-2.4,2.5-4.8,3.8-7.2c1.3-2.3,3-7.3,5.3-8.7
c-1,0-1.9,0-2.9,0c0.6,3.5,0,6.9,0,10.4c0,3.3,0.2,6.7,0.4,10c0.3,6.9,0.4,13.8,0.3,20.7c-0.2,13.8-1.3,27.5-2.9,41.2
c-1.6,13.6-3.2,27.6-6.4,41c-1.7,7-4.8,13.6-7.8,20.2c-2.3,4.9-5.9,10.1-6.5,15.6C90.6,165.9,95.6,162.7,95.8,160.7L95.8,160.7z
 M117.6,488.6c3.5-24,0.7-48.3,1.1-72.5c0-1.8-2.1-1.1-2.9-0.4c-1.5,1.1-4.5,5.2-1.4,6.5c3.6,1.5,4.7-4.5,4.3-6.5s-3.6,0.6-4,1.2
c-7.9,10-13.4,21.5-17.9,33.4c-2.4,6.3-4.6,12.6-7,18.9c-1.1,2.9-2.2,5.7-3.4,8.6c-1.5,3.6-1.9,7.5-3.3,11.1
c-1.2,3.1,3.9,0.5,4.6-1.3c1.2-3.1,1.5-6.4,2.6-9.6c1.1-2.9,2.3-5.7,3.4-8.6c2.2-5.8,4.2-11.6,6.4-17.3c4.5-12.1,9.7-23.9,17.8-34.1
c-1.3,0.4-2.7,0.8-4,1.2c0.1,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.2,1.4c1-1,2-2,3.1-2.9c1.5-0.2,1.3,0.3-0.4,1.5c-1-0.1-1.9-0.3-2.9-0.4
c-0.5,24.2,2.3,48.4-1.1,72.5C112.4,493.7,117.3,490.6,117.6,488.6L117.6,488.6z M162.8,233.2c0.1,11-0.7,22-0.1,33
c0.6,11.5,0.7,23.1,0.9,34.6c0.2,10.3,0.5,20.8,1.1,31.1c0.6,10.7,0.4,21.5,1.2,32.2c0.2,2.9,5-0.4,4.8-2.4
c-0.8-10.3-0.9-20.7-1.1-31c-0.2-10.7-1-21.5-1.1-32.2c-0.2-11.3-0.4-22.6-0.9-33.8c-0.5-11.3,0.2-22.5,0-33.8
C167.6,227.9,162.8,231.2,162.8,233.2L162.8,233.2z M162,232.9c2.3,3.9,8.1,5.1,12.2,5.8c5.7,1,11.5,0.6,17.3,0.4
c7.1-0.3,19.3,0.2,21.4-8.9c0.7-3.1-0.3-4.7-3.4-5.1c-4.5-0.6-9.6-0.6-14.2-0.6c-9.6,0.1-19-1.6-28.4,0.9c-1.9,0.5-4.8,5.4-1.5,4.6
c12.1-3.2,25.4,0,37.8-0.2c2,0,8.6,1,3.1,3.5c-1.4,0.6-4,0.5-5.5,0.6c-4.2,0.4-8.3,0.4-12.5,0.5c-6.2,0.2-18.3,0.6-22-5.8
C165.3,227.1,160.8,230.9,162,232.9L162,232.9z M164.8,309.5c6.3,0.5,12.3,3,18.6,3.7c6.8,0.8,14.5,0.2,21.2-0.8
c1.9-0.3,5.2-5.2,2.6-4.8c-7,1.1-14.8,1.5-21.9,0.8c-6.1-0.7-11.8-3.1-17.9-3.6C165.4,304.6,161.9,309.3,164.8,309.5L164.8,309.5z
 M177.9,430.3c11,1.5,21.7-0.2,32.6-2.1c2-0.3,4.9-5.2,1.5-4.6c-10.1,1.7-20.2,3.4-30.5,2C179.4,425.4,175.8,430.1,177.9,430.3
L177.9,430.3z M207.2,231.5c0.9,34.6-2.5,69.1-1.7,103.6s3.4,68.9,4,103.4c0.1,9.2,0.3,18.4-0.3,27.5c-0.3,4.6-1.2,9.1-1.2,13.7
c0,4.1,0.7,8.1,1.3,12.1c0.3,2.1,5.1-1.3,4.7-3.4c-0.6-4-1.3-7.9-1.2-12c0.1-4,0.9-8,1.1-11.9c0.6-8.3,0.5-16.6,0.4-24.9
c-0.3-16.7-1-33.4-1.6-50c-1.4-34.2-3-68.2-1.7-102.4c0.7-19.4,1.5-38.8,1-58.2C212,226.2,207.1,229.5,207.2,231.5L207.2,231.5z
 M133.3,368.5c0,41,0.1,82,2.8,122.9c0.2,2.9,5-0.4,4.8-2.4c-2.8-40.9-2.8-81.9-2.8-122.9C138.1,363.3,133.3,366.5,133.3,368.5
L133.3,368.5z M132.4,368.3c2.3,3.9,8.1,5.1,12.2,5.8c5.7,1,11.5,0.6,17.3,0.4c7.1-0.3,19.3,0.2,21.4-8.9c0.7-3.1-0.3-4.7-3.4-5.1
c-4.5-0.6-9.6-0.6-14.2-0.6c-9.6,0.1-19-1.6-28.4,0.9c-1.9,0.5-4.8,5.4-1.5,4.6c12.1-3.2,25.4,0,37.8-0.2c2,0,8.6,1,3.1,3.5
c-1.4,0.6-4,0.5-5.5,0.6c-4.2,0.4-8.3,0.4-12.5,0.5c-6.2,0.2-18.3,0.6-22-5.8C135.8,362.4,131.3,366.3,132.4,368.3L132.4,368.3z
 M135.2,444.8c6.3,0.5,12.3,3,18.6,3.7c6.8,0.8,14.5,0.2,21.2-0.8c1.9-0.3,5.2-5.2,2.6-4.8c-7,1.1-14.8,1.5-21.9,0.8
c-6.1-0.7-11.8-3.1-17.9-3.6C135.9,439.9,132.4,444.6,135.2,444.8L135.2,444.8z M177.7,366.8c-0.4,41.9-2.3,83.7-1.3,125.6
c0.1,2.8,4.9-0.4,4.8-2.4c-1-41.9,0.9-83.7,1.3-125.6C182.5,361.6,177.7,364.8,177.7,366.8L177.7,366.8z"/>

 
</svg>
```

### SVG solution

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 1900 1100" class="svg-content" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path class="path"   fill="none" stroke-dasharray="7937" stroke-dasharray="7937" stroke="#51712D" stroke-width="3" 
    d="M216.5,430c13.5-11.8,24.6-24.8,31.3-41.5c3.7-9.2,6.6-18.7,9.3-28.3c2.8-9.8,5.9-19.6,8-29.6
c0.3-1.2-1.5-0.6-1.9-0.3c-9.5,7.5-16.8,18.8-23.7,28.7c-1.5,2.2,1.1,2.3,2.2,0.7c6.4-9.2,13.2-20.2,22.2-27.2
c-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.2-1.9-0.3c-2,9.7-5.1,19.3-7.8,28.8c-2.4,8.5-5.1,16.9-8.1,25.1c-3,8.1-6.8,16.1-12.1,23
c-5.2,7-12.3,13.5-18.8,19.2C213.2,430.1,214.7,431.6,216.5,430L216.5,430z M211.4,428c10.1-14,21.5-28.2,26.6-45
c3.7-12.3,3.9-25.1,3.6-37.8c-0.3-13.9-0.7-28.4-2.8-42.1c-0.2-1.5-2.7,0.4-3,0.9c-6.7,9-10.6,20.6-14.4,31
c-4.6,12.6-7.9,25.9-9.7,39.2c-0.9,6.5-1,13.2-1.1,19.7c-0.1,4.6,0.4,9.3-0.1,13.9c-0.7,6.7-2.7,13.7-2.6,20.4
c0,2.1,3.6-0.3,3.6-1.8c-0.1-6.3,1.7-12.9,2.5-19.1c1.2-9.8,0.2-19.9,0.8-29.8c0.9-12.8,4-25.9,8.1-38.1
c3.9-11.5,7.9-24.8,15.3-34.7c-1,0.3-2,0.6-3,0.9c2.1,13.5,2.4,27.8,2.7,41.4c0.3,12.4,0.2,25-3.4,36.9
c-4.8,16.1-15.9,29.7-25.6,43.2C207.3,429.6,210.2,429.8,211.4,428L211.4,428z M87.2,151.5c-0.2,16.7,0.3,33.3-0.4,50
c-0.6,15.8-0.4,31.7-1.3,47.5c-0.9,15.7-1.7,31.6-2.3,47.4c-0.7,16.5-1.4,32.9-1.4,49.4c-0.1,35.7-0.4,71.5-0.2,107.2
c0.1,13.2,0.2,26.4,0.2,39.6c0,2.8,4.8-0.4,4.8-2.4c-0.1-28.8-0.3-57.6-0.5-86.5c-0.3-48.9,0.7-97.9,3.6-146.7
c1-17.4,1.3-34.9,1.7-52.3c0.2-8.6,0.6-17.2,0.9-25.8c0.3-9.9-0.5-19.9-0.3-29.8C92.1,146.2,87.2,149.4,87.2,151.5L87.2,151.5z
 M88.4,149.8c0.7-1,0.3-0.9-1.2,0.4c-1.1,0.6-2.3,1-3.5,1.4c-2,0.6-4.1,1-6.2,1.3c-3.9,0.5-7.8,0.2-11.7,0.1
c-3.6-0.1-22.9,0.8-19.8-7.1c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.5-1.8,2.3c1.3-0.8,4.9,0,6.4,0c1.8-0.1,3.6-0.5,5.4-0.6c3.4-0.2,6.8-0.1,10.2-0.2
c7-0.3,14-0.8,20.8,1c2,0.5,5.8-4,3.6-4.6c-9.5-2.5-19.1-0.8-28.8-0.9c-2.9,0-5.7,0.5-8.5,0.6c-2.2,0.1-4.4-0.3-6.5,0.1
c-3.3,0.5-5.8,2.8-5.7,6.3c0.1,4.2,3.7,6.3,7.4,6.9c6.5,1.1,13.1,0.9,19.6,1.1c7.8,0.3,21.5-0.8,25-9.3
C94.3,145.4,89.2,147.9,88.4,149.8L88.4,149.8z M90.1,224.4c-6,0.5-11.6,2.9-17.5,3.6c-7.3,0.8-15.3,0.5-22.5-0.6
c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c7,1.1,15,1.7,22,0.9c6.4-0.7,12.6-3.2,19-3.8C89.4,229,92.8,224.2,90.1,224.4L90.1,224.4z M82.6,344.2
c-2.1,2.2-3.5,2.8-6.7,3.4c-3.3,0.6-6.6,0.5-9.9,0.5c-7.3-0.1-14.3-1.2-21.5-2.5c-2.1-0.4-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c9,1.6,17.6,2.8,26.9,2.6
c6.7-0.2,12.4-1.4,16.9-6.3C87.3,343.9,85.1,341.5,82.6,344.2L82.6,344.2z M42,149.7c0.3,44.3,2.2,88.6,1.4,132.9
c-0.4,22.2-1.8,44.4-2.5,66.6c-0.7,22.6-1.4,45.2-2.1,67.8c-0.4,12.4-0.8,24.8-1.3,37.3c-0.2,6.2-0.5,12.4-0.8,18.6
c-0.1,3.2-0.5,6.5-0.4,9.8c0.1,2.4,0.8,4.6,0.6,7c-0.2,2.7,4.7-0.4,4.8-2.4c0.1-1.6-0.1-3.1-0.3-4.7c-0.4-3-0.1-6,0-9.1
c0.2-5.5,0.5-11.1,0.7-16.6c0.4-11.1,0.8-22.2,1.2-33.3c0.7-22.3,1.4-44.5,2.1-66.8c1.4-44.8,3.4-89.3,2.7-134.1
c-0.4-25.3-1.1-50.4-1.3-75.4C46.8,144.4,42,147.7,42,149.7L42,149.7z M7.5,37c0.4,59.5,3,119,1.8,178.5C8.7,244.9,7,274.4,6,303.8
c-1,30.2-1.8,60.4-2.8,90.6c-0.5,16.4-1.1,32.8-1.7,49.1c-0.3,8.5-0.7,17-1,25.5c-0.2,3.9-0.6,7.9-0.5,11.7c0.1,3.2,1.1,6.2,0.7,9.4
c-0.4,3.6,6.1-0.6,6.5-3.3c0.3-2.6-0.3-4.9-0.6-7.5c-0.3-3.2,0-6.5,0.2-9.7c0.3-7.8,0.7-15.7,1-23.5C8.4,431,8.9,416,9.4,400.9
c1-29.5,1.8-59.1,2.8-88.6c0.9-29.5,1.9-58.9,3.2-88.3c1.3-30.1,0.8-60.2,0.3-90.3c-0.6-33.3-1.4-66.6-1.7-99.9
C13.9,30,7.5,34.3,7.5,37L7.5,37z M57.1,36.5c-0.2,17.7,0.2,35.4-0.5,53.2c-0.6,16.8-1.6,33.8-1.5,50.5c0,2.8,4.9-0.4,4.8-2.4
c-0.1-16.8,0.9-33.8,1.5-50.5c0.7-17.8,0.3-35.4,0.5-53.2C62,31.2,57.1,34.4,57.1,36.5L57.1,36.5z M58.3,34.8c0.7-1,0.3-0.9-1.2,0.4
c-1.1,0.6-2.3,1-3.5,1.4c-2,0.6-4.1,1-6.2,1.3c-3.9,0.5-7.8,0.2-11.7,0.1c-3.6-0.1-22.9,0.8-19.8-7.1c-0.6,0.8-1.2,1.5-1.8,2.3
c1.3-0.8,4.9,0,6.4,0c1.8-0.1,3.6-0.5,5.4-0.6c3.4-0.2,6.8-0.1,10.2-0.2c7-0.3,14-0.8,20.8,1c2,0.5,5.8-4,3.6-4.6
C51,26.3,41.4,28,31.7,27.9c-2.9,0-5.7,0.5-8.5,0.6c-2.2,0.1-4.4-0.3-6.5,0.1c-3.3,0.5-5.8,2.8-5.7,6.3c0.1,4.2,3.7,6.3,7.4,6.9
c6.5,1.1,13.1,0.9,19.6,1.1c7.8,0.3,21.5-0.8,25-9.3C64.2,30.4,59.1,32.9,58.3,34.8L58.3,34.8z M60,109.4c-6,0.5-11.6,2.9-17.5,3.6
c-7.3,0.8-15.3,0.5-22.5-0.6c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c7,1.1,15,1.7,22,0.9c6.4-0.7,12.6-3.2,19-3.8C59.3,114,62.7,109.2,60,109.4
L60,109.4z M44.6,370.7c-11.2,2.7-22,3.6-33.6,1.7c-2.1-0.3-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6c6,1,13.3,1.8,19.3,1.3c5.7-0.5,10.8-1.7,16.3-3.1
C45.1,374.8,47.9,369.9,44.6,370.7L44.6,370.7z M46.1,232.6c-10.7,1.4-21.1-0.2-31.6-2c-2.1-0.4-5.7,4.3-3.6,4.6
c10.8,1.9,21.6,3.6,32.6,2.2C45.5,237.1,48.8,232.3,46.1,232.6L46.1,232.6z M91.1,182c-0.1-4.9,2.5-10.2,4.3-14.7
c1.9-4.6,3.8-9.2,5.7-13.9c4-10.2,9.7-18.8,16.2-27.7c6-8.1,11.3-16.8,17.8-24.6c3.6-4.3,7.6-8.1,11.9-11.6c3.7-3,7.7-7.5,11.8-9.8
c-0.7,0-1.3,0-2,0c1.9,2.3,0.9,7.7,0.9,10.5c0,3.9-0.1,7.9-0.4,11.8c-0.6,7.8-2.2,15.5-4,23.1c-3.5,14.8-8.8,29.4-15.3,43.2
c-6.2,13.1-13.9,26.9-23.3,37.9c-4.7,5.5-10.2,10.2-15.6,15.1c-2.5,2.3-4.8,4.7-7,7.3c-1.6,1.8-3.3,3-4,5.3c-1,3.3,4,0.6,4.6-1.3
c0.3-1,4.7-5.3,6-6.6c2.7-2.7,5.7-5.2,8.5-7.8c5.4-5,10.5-10.3,14.9-16.2c8.8-12.1,16.5-25.7,22.4-39.4
c6.3-14.6,11.5-29.7,14.8-45.3c1.6-7.4,2.7-14.7,3-22.3c0.2-4.2,0.2-8.5,0.2-12.7c0-2.4,0.2-4.8-1.5-6.7c-0.5-0.6-1.5-0.2-2,0
c-4.3,2.4-7.9,6.4-11.7,9.4c-4.3,3.5-8.4,7-12.2,11c-8,8.6-14.2,19-21.1,28.4c-6.5,8.8-12.5,17.5-16.6,27.7
c-2.2,5.4-4.4,10.8-6.6,16.2c-2,4.9-4.7,10.5-4.6,15.9C86.3,187.2,91.1,184,91.1,182L91.1,182z M95.8,160.7c0.4-3.8,3.3-8,4.9-11.5
c1.2-2.5,2.3-5.1,3.5-7.6c2.7-6.2,5.1-12.4,6.5-19c2.8-13.3,4.6-27,6.1-40.5c1.6-14,2.6-28.1,2.7-42.2c0-6.9-0.1-13.7-0.5-20.6
c-0.3-6.1,0.7-12.6-0.3-18.6c-0.2-1.4-2.3-0.3-2.9,0c-3.9,2.5-5.8,7.4-8,11.3c-3,5.5-5.9,11-8.3,16.7c-5.3,12.3-9.9,25-14.1,37.7
c-4.1,12.5-8.5,25.4-10.7,38.4c-2.2,13.4-3.4,27-3.9,40.6c-0.1,2.8,4.8-0.4,4.8-2.4c0.4-12,1.6-24,3.2-36
c1.7-12.4,5.7-24.5,9.5-36.5c3.5-11.2,7.5-22.2,11.7-33.1c2.3-5.9,4.7-11.9,7.6-17.6c1.2-2.4,2.5-4.8,3.8-7.2c1.3-2.3,3-7.3,5.3-8.7
c-1,0-1.9,0-2.9,0c0.6,3.5,0,6.9,0,10.4c0,3.3,0.2,6.7,0.4,10c0.3,6.9,0.4,13.8,0.3,20.7c-0.2,13.8-1.3,27.5-2.9,41.2
c-1.6,13.6-3.2,27.6-6.4,41c-1.7,7-4.8,13.6-7.8,20.2c-2.3,4.9-5.9,10.1-6.5,15.6C90.6,165.9,95.6,162.7,95.8,160.7L95.8,160.7z
 M117.6,488.6c3.5-24,0.7-48.3,1.1-72.5c0-1.8-2.1-1.1-2.9-0.4c-1.5,1.1-4.5,5.2-1.4,6.5c3.6,1.5,4.7-4.5,4.3-6.5s-3.6,0.6-4,1.2
c-7.9,10-13.4,21.5-17.9,33.4c-2.4,6.3-4.6,12.6-7,18.9c-1.1,2.9-2.2,5.7-3.4,8.6c-1.5,3.6-1.9,7.5-3.3,11.1
c-1.2,3.1,3.9,0.5,4.6-1.3c1.2-3.1,1.5-6.4,2.6-9.6c1.1-2.9,2.3-5.7,3.4-8.6c2.2-5.8,4.2-11.6,6.4-17.3c4.5-12.1,9.7-23.9,17.8-34.1
c-1.3,0.4-2.7,0.8-4,1.2c0.1,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.2,1.4c1-1,2-2,3.1-2.9c1.5-0.2,1.3,0.3-0.4,1.5c-1-0.1-1.9-0.3-2.9-0.4
c-0.5,24.2,2.3,48.4-1.1,72.5C112.4,493.7,117.3,490.6,117.6,488.6L117.6,488.6z M162.8,233.2c0.1,11-0.7,22-0.1,33
c0.6,11.5,0.7,23.1,0.9,34.6c0.2,10.3,0.5,20.8,1.1,31.1c0.6,10.7,0.4,21.5,1.2,32.2c0.2,2.9,5-0.4,4.8-2.4
c-0.8-10.3-0.9-20.7-1.1-31c-0.2-10.7-1-21.5-1.1-32.2c-0.2-11.3-0.4-22.6-0.9-33.8c-0.5-11.3,0.2-22.5,0-33.8
C167.6,227.9,162.8,231.2,162.8,233.2L162.8,233.2z M162,232.9c2.3,3.9,8.1,5.1,12.2,5.8c5.7,1,11.5,0.6,17.3,0.4
c7.1-0.3,19.3,0.2,21.4-8.9c0.7-3.1-0.3-4.7-3.4-5.1c-4.5-0.6-9.6-0.6-14.2-0.6c-9.6,0.1-19-1.6-28.4,0.9c-1.9,0.5-4.8,5.4-1.5,4.6
c12.1-3.2,25.4,0,37.8-0.2c2,0,8.6,1,3.1,3.5c-1.4,0.6-4,0.5-5.5,0.6c-4.2,0.4-8.3,0.4-12.5,0.5c-6.2,0.2-18.3,0.6-22-5.8
C165.3,227.1,160.8,230.9,162,232.9L162,232.9z M164.8,309.5c6.3,0.5,12.3,3,18.6,3.7c6.8,0.8,14.5,0.2,21.2-0.8
c1.9-0.3,5.2-5.2,2.6-4.8c-7,1.1-14.8,1.5-21.9,0.8c-6.1-0.7-11.8-3.1-17.9-3.6C165.4,304.6,161.9,309.3,164.8,309.5L164.8,309.5z
 M177.9,430.3c11,1.5,21.7-0.2,32.6-2.1c2-0.3,4.9-5.2,1.5-4.6c-10.1,1.7-20.2,3.4-30.5,2C179.4,425.4,175.8,430.1,177.9,430.3
L177.9,430.3z M207.2,231.5c0.9,34.6-2.5,69.1-1.7,103.6s3.4,68.9,4,103.4c0.1,9.2,0.3,18.4-0.3,27.5c-0.3,4.6-1.2,9.1-1.2,13.7
c0,4.1,0.7,8.1,1.3,12.1c0.3,2.1,5.1-1.3,4.7-3.4c-0.6-4-1.3-7.9-1.2-12c0.1-4,0.9-8,1.1-11.9c0.6-8.3,0.5-16.6,0.4-24.9
c-0.3-16.7-1-33.4-1.6-50c-1.4-34.2-3-68.2-1.7-102.4c0.7-19.4,1.5-38.8,1-58.2C212,226.2,207.1,229.5,207.2,231.5L207.2,231.5z
 M133.3,368.5c0,41,0.1,82,2.8,122.9c0.2,2.9,5-0.4,4.8-2.4c-2.8-40.9-2.8-81.9-2.8-122.9C138.1,363.3,133.3,366.5,133.3,368.5
L133.3,368.5z M132.4,368.3c2.3,3.9,8.1,5.1,12.2,5.8c5.7,1,11.5,0.6,17.3,0.4c7.1-0.3,19.3,0.2,21.4-8.9c0.7-3.1-0.3-4.7-3.4-5.1
c-4.5-0.6-9.6-0.6-14.2-0.6c-9.6,0.1-19-1.6-28.4,0.9c-1.9,0.5-4.8,5.4-1.5,4.6c12.1-3.2,25.4,0,37.8-0.2c2,0,8.6,1,3.1,3.5
c-1.4,0.6-4,0.5-5.5,0.6c-4.2,0.4-8.3,0.4-12.5,0.5c-6.2,0.2-18.3,0.6-22-5.8C135.8,362.4,131.3,366.3,132.4,368.3L132.4,368.3z
 M135.2,444.8c6.3,0.5,12.3,3,18.6,3.7c6.8,0.8,14.5,0.2,21.2-0.8c1.9-0.3,5.2-5.2,2.6-4.8c-7,1.1-14.8,1.5-21.9,0.8
c-6.1-0.7-11.8-3.1-17.9-3.6C135.9,439.9,132.4,444.6,135.2,444.8L135.2,444.8z M177.7,366.8c-0.4,41.9-2.3,83.7-1.3,125.6
c0.1,2.8,4.9-0.4,4.8-2.4c-1-41.9,0.9-83.7,1.3-125.6C182.5,361.6,177.7,364.8,177.7,366.8L177.7,366.8z">

 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="7937;0" dur="64s" fill="freeze"  />
   </path>
</svg>
```